# unable to declare class without initialization?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, initialization

For standard data objects such like int, the following can be done

```
    int number;
    number = 0;
```

Basically, you can declare number before initializing it, useful if you initialize inside various if statements and you don't want number going out of scope.

Can something similar be done with custom classes?

I have a class called mem_array with constructor of the form

```
    mem_array(int,int,std::string);
```

I would like to do the following

```
      mem_array myData;
      if(x==0) myData(1,1,"up");
      if(x==1) myData(0,0,"down");
```

basically, so I can use myData outside of the scope of the if statements.  Can something like this be done?

Comment: Would `myData.initialize(1,1,"up")` be good enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first line will give you an error since the constructor doesnt have default values and a constructor without parameters doesnt exist.

Just use a pointer (or even better a smart pointer, so you dont have to take care of deleting the object). But be sure to check afterwards that x was either 0 or 1, i.e. check that myData has been constructed.

```
mem_array* myData=0;
if(x==0) myData=new mem_array(1,1,"up");
if(x==1) myData=new mem_array(0,0,"down);

assert(myData!=0);
```

Comment: Right, and then don't forget to call a delete.. What about if he wants it on stack or if operator new is declared private?

Comment: ... why would you make operator new private?

Comment: As I said, using smart pointers would be better here which solves 1. the delete problem, and 2. the behaviour is similar to the "on-the-stack" behaviour. Leaving scope deletes the object.
And a private new? There might be some rare cases where you do that but I cant imagine any right off the bat. And besides, he didnt ask for that.

Comment: does the separate initialization work if we write a dummy blank constructor?

Answer (score 2):

add a constructor to mem_array that takes an int

so that you can declare/use...

mem_array myData(x);

inside this constructor, add the initialization/condition code you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pointer:

```
unique_ptr<mem_array> myData;
switch (x) {
case 0:
    myData.reset(new mem_array(1, 1, "up"));
    break;
case 1:
    myData.reset(new mem_array(0, 0, "down"));;
    break;
}
```

Comment: And nobody mentioned placement new... Why on earth allocate memory dynamically for this?

Comment: @Vlad: How would you RAII using placement new?

Comment: @bdonlan: That's for sure! :)

Comment: How do you think you RAII in C, for example?

Answer (score 1):

```
int number;
number = 0;
```

That last line explicitly is `number = int(0);`.  In other words, use the type:

```
mem_array myData;
if (x == 0) myData = mem_array(1, 1, "up");
if (x == 1) myData = mem_array(0, 0, "down");
```

This unfortunately requires you to overload operator=():

```
class mem_array
{
   ...
 public:
  mem_array& operator= (const mem_array& cma);
  {
    /* Copy the information from cma to *this. */

    /* Return a reference to this object. */
    return *this;
  }
};
```

An alternative is to use pointers (dynamic allocation) as others have recommended.  It's up to you which you use in the end.

Comment: If you're doing this, you need to also provide a default and copy constructor

Answer (score 1):

The `?:` operator is underrated.

```
mem_array myData = (x==1) ? myData(1,1,"up") : myData(0,0,"down");
```

Answer (score 0):

Declaration like that automatically calls the default constructor (i.e. with no argument or with all arguments have default value). The compiler would create it automatically when your class doesn't have any constructor, but since you have one, then it won't be created automatically. Therefore, the declaration fails because it can't find the default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use `boost::optional<T>`. This makes it explicit that your variable can hold the value not-a-T. E.g.

```
boost::optional<mem_array> myData; // Doesn't hold a mem_array yet.
if(x==0) myData = mem_array(1,1,"up");
if(x==1) myData = mem_array(0,0,"down");
```